# Sql query returns single or multiple records?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Within my stored procedure I execute another stored procedure. Here is an example

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL --CAN RETURN MULTIPLE RECORDS
```

Then

I need to execute my stored procedure and pass parameters ID from the query above

So if the query above returns two IDs I need to execute the stored procedure below 2 times. The way I think is to create a loop but more than sure it's not the most efficient way.

```
EXEC StoredProcedureName ID
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if it's possible for you use function instead stored procedure and put it right in select statment

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cursor and loop through it and call you procedure.

For example

```
DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE some_cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL

OPEN some_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor 
INTO @ID 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC StoredProcedureName @ID

    FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor 
     INTO @ID 


END
CLOSE some_cursor ;
DEALLOCATE some_cursor;
```

As you'll notice its clumsy to write and its SQL can't optimize what ever `StoredProcedureName` is doing for more than one input.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use a loop (whether it explicitly uses DECLARE CURSOR or not is largely irrelevant), or you need to extract the logic in StoredProcedureName such that it can work on a set instead of a single value at a time.

Comment: You need to show us the code for StoredProcedureName. Can't guess what it's doing. Maybe start a new question such as "How do I make this code work on a set..."

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @value INT
 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT value FROM YourTable
 open cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @value
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
      exec YourProcedure @value
      exec AnotherProcedure @value
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @value
 END
 CLOSE cur
 DEALLOCATE Cur
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you alter your stored procedure?

You could perhaps incorporate the

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL
```

query into the stored procedure rather than passing in parameters.